# Book with a medieval planet in a sci-fi setting but inhabitants not aware

Tags: story-identification, books

I do not know if I was dreaming but I can swear I read a book about a medieval planet where the technology level was medieval, but that the elite or the rulers knew of the space-faring civilizations and traded with them. A Star Trek book seems a likely candidate with the Prime Directive but I know it was not Star Trek. It could have been a Star Wars EU book but I doubt it.

The book seems to follow two or three different characters. One is a regular character unaware living daily life on the planet, another is a merchant or agent of a space-faring civilization, and another is of the nobility, perhaps.

If I recall, in a similar way to the Prime Directive, there is some kind of strict blockade around the planet and strict rules regarding contact as well as trade. Perhaps there is no trade at all but rather traveling agents.

Comment: This is a very common trope. I think the most recent one I can think of is Iain M. Banks' "[Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_(novel))"

Comment: That was not it, but thank you for the tip. This was a world that was cutoff like the Prime Directive, but the royalty knew of trade with 'offworlders' and the ships were disguised.

Comment: Can I get you to take a look [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can add in anymore details?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImportedAlienPhlebotinum

Comment: @Seanchaí - You're still describing the characters from "Matter".

Comment: @Valorum This would have been read over 5 years ago though, and definitely is a solar system to my remembrance. Not a ring world.

Comment: Can you say more on the charecters do they get transformed at any point?

Comment: I don't remember. Anything in mind that vaguely resembles this?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_to_Be_a_God?

Comment: This makes me think of _[Glory Season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_Season)_ for some reason, but it's been too long since I read all of it to be sure of the connection.

Comment: There was a Doctor Who book "Royal Blood" by Una McCormack that has a garbled relationship to this (medieval society with technological devices, a couple of independently-arriving parties in the plot one of whom collects technological gadgets) but it wouldn't have been published that long ago, and if your book had somebody in it claiming to be Lancelot, you would have remembered. So, it's not that.